# Северо(-)американский

Tags: орфография

Меня тут запутали. Всегда казалось, что слово "североамериканский" пишется слитно в любом случае, но знакомые утверждают, что, если речь идет о континенте, то надо писать через дефис.
Правда ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово «североамериканский» пишется слитно.  Это относительное прилагательное, образованное на основе словосочетания Северная Америка С ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНОЙ СВЯЗЬЮ . Также: Западная Сибирь – западносибирские реки. Обратим внимание на усечение суффикса Н: североамериканский, но: южноамериканский.

Через дефис пишутся: ИМЕНА СОБСТВЕННЫЕ с первой частью СЕВЕРО-: Северо-Атлантическое течение,  Северо-Американский хребет, Северо-Чуйский хребет, Северо-Двинский канал, Северо-Корейские горы, Северо-Атлантический хребет.

Но: Североатлантический договор – это договор страны Северной Атлантики.

Также через дефис пишутся сложные прилагательные, если они образованы от сложных существительных с дефисным написанием: северо-восток – северо-восточный.

Answer (score 1):

Насчет Вашего вопроса точно ничего не скажу, так как достаточно плохо знаю эту тему. А вот у Вас в примере я нашел ошибку: перед **если** в данном случае не нужна запятая, так как есть частица **то** после **если**. Если же ее не будет, то тогда можете смело ставить запятую, то есть:

Меня тут запутали. Всегда казалось, что слово "североамериканский" пишется слитно в любом случае, но знакомые утверждают, что (здесь не нужна, так как есть частица то) если речь идет о континенте, то надо писать через дефис.
Правда ли это?

Меня тут запутали. Всегда казалось, что слово "североамериканский" пишется слитно в любом случае, но знакомые утверждают, что, если речь идет о континенте, надо писать через дефис.
Правда ли это?

Во втором варианте мы убрали частицу **то**, поэтому ставится запятая перед **если**.

Так же и с союзом **когда**.

Я знаю, что когда ты придешь, тогда мы будем играть в футбол. Наличие **тогда** говорит о том, что запятая перед **когда** не требуется.

Я знаю, что, когда ты приедешь, мы будем развлекаться.

Эта тема, насколько я понял, называется "запятая на стыке союзов". Если захотите ознакомиться поподробнее –– http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188.

Comment: Тагир, тему нельзя знать "достаточно плохо", здесь нарушена сочетаемость слов. Обычно сначала человек ничего не знает о предмете, затем что-то знает, но "недостаточно хорошо". И только в какой-то момент достигается определенная граница его осведомленности, когда можно сказать: он знает это  "достаточно хорошо", хорошо, очень хорошо и т.д.

Comment: Благодарю за поправку.